# Jquery inview adding class to last element

Tags: jquery, inview

I'm trying to use the jquery inview plugin to add a class to an element when it's within the viewport. For some reason the plugin in only adding the class to the very last element even though the other elements are clearly visible in the viewport. Below is my code:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <article class="entry"></article>
     <article class="entry"></article>
     <article class="entry"></article>
     <article class="entry"></article>
     <article class="entry"></article>
     <article class="entry"></article>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.entry').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        if (visible) {
            $(this).addClass('show-post');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put you script inside ready:I'm changing the color to green to show the effect that the class `show-post` is added.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jquery.inview - Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://protonet.info/wp-content/themes/protonet/js/jquery.inview.js"></script>

<style>
.show-post{
color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
     <article class="entry">hi</article>
     <article class="entry">sfsdf</article>
     <article class="entry">sdfsd</article>
     <article class="entry">sdfds</article>
     <article class="entry">sdfds</article>
     <article class="entry">sdfs</article>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.entry').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
     if (visible) {
         $(this).addClass('show-post');
     }
 });
 
 });
</script>
</footer></html>
```

Comment: I actually do have it in $(function() {.... But it's in the footer not the header.

Comment: Try adopting this and see if it is giving any problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer see if this is what you want.